# Auf {einen, einem} Baum klettern - Akkusativ oder Dativ?

Tags: grammar

Ich habe den folgenden Satz geschrieben:

> Eine Katze ist auf **einen** Baum geklettert.

Meine Deutschlehrerin hat mich korrigiert und geschrieben:

> Eine Katze ist auf **einem** Baum geklettert.

Was ist richtig? Was ist falsch? Warum?

**EDIT**: Ich musste ein Bild beschreiben. Es gab eine Katze, die auf einem Baum war und Hilfe brauchte. So, ich habe geschrieben:

> Eine Katze ist auf einen Baum geklettert. Vielleicht braucht sie
>   Hilfe.

Comment: Nach Verben der Bewegung Akkusativ (wohin), nach Verben der Position Dativ (wo). Die Katze klettert/springt auf einen Baum. Die Katze ist/sitzt/versteckt sich auf einem Baum. Deine Lehrerin liegt hier also falsch.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Beide Sätze sind korrekt, haben aber unterschiedliche Bedeutungen.

> Eine Katze ist auf einen Baum geklettert.

ist richtig, wenn die Katze zuerst auf dem Boden war und danach auf den Baum geklettert ist - was in 99% der Fälle richtig sein wird.

> Eine Katze ist auf einem Baum (herum-)geklettert.

sagt aus, dass die Katze bereits auf dem Baum war und dort oben herumgeklettert ist. Die Katze war entweder bereits auf dem Baum, als der Erzähler sie entdeckt hat, oder der Erzähler möchte betonen, was die Katze auf dem Baum gemacht hat und nicht, dass/wie sie dort hinaufgekommen ist. Als Muttersprachler würde man hier jedoch das Verb *herumklettern* benutzen. Das Präfix *herum-* gibt es für die meisten Verben, die eine Fortbewegung anzeigen (*laufen*, *rennen*, *fliegen* etc.), und sollte immer dann vorangestellt werden, wenn im Satz keine Richtung bzw. kein Ziel der Fortbewegung vorkommt und nur die Bewegung an sich entscheidend ist.

Der erste Satz betont somit die Bewegung der Katze vom Boden auf den Baum (**wohin**), während der zweite Satz schon voraussetzt, dass die Katze sich auf dem Baum befindet (**wo**) und eher beschreibt, was die Katze auf dem Baum macht. Da die erste Möglichkeit in der Regel spektakulärer ist und wohl am häufigsten vorkommt, vermute ich, dass sich deine Deutschlehrerin hier geirrt hat, je nach Kontext.

Comment: Ich musste ein Bild beschreiben. Es gab eine Katze, die auf einem Baum war und Hilfe brauchte. So, ich habe geschrieben: "Eine Katze ist auf **einen** Baum geklettert. Vielleicht braucht sie Hilfe."

Comment: Es ist eine logische Konsequenz, dass die Katze zuvor auf de**n** Baum geklettert sein muss, wenn sie auf dem Baum ist. Somit war dein Satz völlig richtig und meiner Meinung nach sogar besser als der Vorschlag deiner Lehrerin. Welche der beiden Möglichkeiten man wählt, hängt davon ab, was man betonen will. In diesem Fall ist eindeutig wichtiger, dass die Katze auf den Baum geklettert ist (und nicht z.B. unten steht). *Auf einem Baum* würde betonen, dass die Katze geklettert ist (und nicht z.B. zufrieden heruntergeschaut hat).

Answer (score 6):

Beides sind grammatikalisch korrekte Sätze, aber bezogen auf die Situation, die Du beschreibst, ist Deine Variante die bessere.

> Eine Katze ist auf **einen** Baum geklettert.

Die Variante mit Akkusativ zeigt die Richtung an ("**Wohin** ist die Katze geklettert?"). Zusammen mit der Zeitform des Perfekts ergibt sich eine Beschreibung eines gegenwärtigen Zustands ("Die Katze ist jetzt oben.") und eine Angabe, wie er erreicht wurde ("Sie ist hinaufgeklettert.") Das paßt sehr gut zu dem, was nach Deiner Beschreibung auf dem Bild zu sehen ist: die Katze ist auf dem Baum, und man kann annehmen, daß sie wohl durch Klettern dahin gekommen ist.

> Eine Katze ist auf **einem** Baum geklettert.

Die Variante mit Dativ antwortet auf die Frage "**Wo** klettert die Katze?". Sie drückt aus, daß die Katze irgendwie auf den Baum gelangt ist und jetzt dort oben herumklettert. Auch das könnte zu dem Bild passen, aber dann würde man den Satz als Bildbeschreibung im Präsens formulieren, also

> Eine Katze klettert auf einem Baum.

Vielleicht wollte Deine Lehrerin, daß Du diesen Aspekt betonst, aber dann hätte sie Dich auch auf die falsche Zeitform hinweisen müssen, denn im Perfekt funktioniert der Satz nicht als Bildbeschreibung. Er drückt dann aus, daß die Katze jetzt nicht mehr klettert und wahrscheinlich sogar schon wieder unten ist.

Auch wenn auf dem Bild zu sehen ist, daß die Katze sich nicht bewegt und offenbar Hilfe braucht, würde der erste Satz besser passen, denn die Hilfsbedürftigkeit entsteht ja eher dadurch, daß die Katze zwar auf **den** Baum (hinauf-)geklettert ist, aber nun nicht wieder herunterkommt - und nicht dadurch, daß sie zuvor eine Weile auf **dem** Baum herumgeklettert ist.

Answer (score 3):

Ich würde hier abhängig vom Kontext wählen. Auf die Frage "Wo ist die Katze?" würde ich antworten: "Sie ist auf einen Baum geklettert.". Auf die Frage "Was hat die Katze denn die ganze Zeit gemacht?" würde ich dann mit "Sie ist auf einem Baum geklettert." beantworten.

Einmal geht es dann um den Ort, einmal um den Zeitvertreib bzw. den Verlauf.

Dieser Erklärungsansatz ist sicherlich unvollständig, führt aber hoffentlich in die richtige Richtung...

Answer (score 1):

Wenn ich meinen Senf noch dazugeben kann.

Für mich klingt

*Eine Katze ist auf einem Baum geklettert*

irgendwie seltsam und nicht normal. Für das, was in den anderen Antworten als Inhalt dieses Satzes beschrieben wurde, würde ich sagen

*Eine Katze ist auf einem Baum herumgeklettert*