# Warum "unter der Brücke hindurchgehen"?

Tags: grammar, preposition, grammatical-case, dative, accusative

Aus dem [Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/hindurchgehen):

> unter der Brücke hindurchgehen

Warum Dativ? Ich habe die Frage "[Auf {einen, einem} Baum klettern - Akkusativ oder Dativ?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/18696/auf-einen-einem-baum-klettern-akkusativ-oder-dativ)" schon gelesen, und ich habe gedacht, dass hier der Akkusativ verwendet werden soll, weil die Person zuvor nicht unter der Brücke war. Warum ist das falsch?

Comment: Danach ist sie auch nicht unter der Brücke.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Man kann es auf zweierlei Weisen sehen.

Zum einen bist du, wenn du unter einer Brücke durchgehst, sowohl davor also auch danach NICHT unter der Brücke. Genau das würde der Akkusativ aber implizieren – dass du in "ein neues Verhältnis" zur Brücke trittst.

Die logischere Variante ist aber wohl, dass der Dativ einfach anzeigt, dass du beim Drunterdurchgehen einfach mal drunter bist.
In gewisser Weise ist "unter der Brücke hindurch" die gleiche Konstruktion wie

> an der Straße entlang/auf und ab/nach Hause.

Man etabliert einen Ort und dann eine Bewegungsrichtung, vielleicht relativ zu diesem (fixen) Ort vielleicht auch nicht.
Was interessant ist, ist die Frage, warum man

> über DIE Brücke hinüber

sagt. Da würde ich dann spekulieren, dass das *über* in diesem Fall schon die Richtung anzeigt, welche das Adverb dann nur nochmal bestärkt. Das macht auch in soweit Sinn, als dass ein Mensch normalerweise *auf* einer Brücke ist, und nicht *über* ihr.

> Ich gehe auf der Brücke hinüber.

Das klingt einfach nicht idiomatisch, bzw. klingt hier ein Fluss mit, den man überquert.
So gesehen passt das dann doch wieder mit dem Originalsatz. Hier ist der Fluss im Weg, da die Brücke.

Answer (score 1):

Anscheinend ist "unter ... hindurch" eine feste Kombination die immer den Dativ bedingt. Auf dieser Website gibt es eine Liste mit allen solchen "Zirkumpositionen" und deren Kasus:

https://files.ifi.uzh.ch/cl/volk/LexMorphVorl/Lexikon07.Prep.html#Zirk

Answer (score 1):

Der Präposition *unter* folgt entweder Dativ oder Akkusativ.

Auf [canoo.net](http://canoonet.eu/services/OnlineGrammar/Wort/Praeposition/Kasus/2Kasus.html?lang=en#Anchor-unter-24819) ist zu lesen:

> with dative when "local", static (wo?)
>   with accusative when "local", dynamic (wohin?)

Obwohl man durch die Bewegung (sprich *gehen*) leicht zu zweiterem verführt wird, handelt es sich aber um eine statische Angabe: **Wo** bewege ich mich hindurch?

In deinem Beispiel folgt also der Dativ; man geht *unter der Brücke* hindurch.

Aber man geht *unter die Brücke*. Hier ist die Frage, **wohin** bewege ich mich? Somit wird dann der Akkusativ verwendet.

Comment: Ja, aber die Frage ist doch warum das als statisch angesehen wird. Weitere interessant Frage ist, warum man "über die Brücke hinüber geht". Nach deiner Antwort sollte es dann hier doch auch "wo" sein. Oder gilt es nur für "hindurch". Dann ist die Frage, warum. Nicht, dass ich letztgültige Antworten hätte, aber mit einem Verweis auf die Standardregeln ist es hier nicht getan. Dann kannst du auch einfach "weil isso" schreiben ;)

Comment: @Emanuel Interessanter Punkt. "Ich gehe unter der Brücke hindurch" -> Das Ziel ist weitesgehend unbekannt (implizit: auf die andere Seite), es ist nur klar, **wo** ich gehe. (Und was ich mache: hindurchgehen). "Hindurch" ist hier sogar wichtig, sonst glaube man, man ginge "unter die Brücke" (man muss hier natürlich den Fall wechseln und beantwortet dann wohin) oder "unter der Brücke hin und her" – "Ich gehe über der Brücke" -> Wo gehe ich? Dativ. Über der Brücke. Etwas merkwürdig natürlich. Ich gehe normalerweise *auf* der Brücke. – To be continued...

Comment: ... "Ich gehe über die Brücke (hinüber)" -> Im Gegensatz zu "unter die/der Brücke" haben wir hier keine 'Verwechslungsgefahr'. Wie schon gesagt, geht man für gewöhnlich nicht über *der* Brücke, und man geht *auf* der Brücke. Der Satz beantwortet also gleich zwei Dinge unmissverständlich: Das Wo und Wohin. Hier ist aber das Ziel der wesentliche Punkt. Nochmals: Vorhin war "hindurch" wichtig, um vom "hin und her bewegen" zu unterscheiden. Das kann hier nicht passieren. Also ist imho der Akkusativ hier nachvollziehbar.

Comment: Jetzt wo ich den zweiten Teil fertig geschrieben habe, stelle ich fest, dass ich im ersten Teil schon den Hinweis zu "unter die Brücke gehen" hätte weglassen können. Hat keine Relevanz. – Und ich seh grad, dass du den Kernpunkt meines Kommentars auch selbst in deiner Antwort erwähnst. :)

Answer (score 0):

Gar nicht so einfach für dieses Problem irgendwie Verständnis zu vermitteln, obwohl ich mich jetzt mehrmals damit beschäftigt habe.

Jedenfalls wird "unter der Brücke" nicht als wohin-Angabe empfunden. Man fragt:
Worunter? Das ist eigentlich "unter was/unter welcher Sache".

Weiß nicht, ob dir das hilft, aber vielleicht hilft es doch etwas.